# Slope of Tangent line of Polar Curve at Point

Tags: polar-coordinates, slope

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZkbB.png)
We had an examination today in college and the question was this:

Find the slope of the tangent line of polar curve $r = 3(1-\cos\theta)$ at point $B(\pi/3, 3/2 )$.

Answers are: $2\pi$, $\pi/3$, $1/2$, $\pi/2$ and 1.

I am no expert in math but nowhere have I ever seen some point in polar coordinate system as $r$ having a value with $\pi$ and $\theta$ with no $\pi$ at all. What kind of a point is $B$ like that. It was an online examination and I took a screenshot of the question so I didn't confuse the places of $r$ and $\theta$. I thought maybe they did and tried to solve the question accordingly, still couldn't find the answer. In other questions there were points given in the answers with $r$ having a value of $\pi$ * something and $\theta$ as a real value with no $\pi$.

Please clarify this I don't know what the problem is. Is there such a thing that they forgot to tell when teaching (that $r$ could be something with $\pi$) or they really made a huge mistake?

Comment: The coordinates of $B$ are usually given as $(r,\theta).$ So you are right, and looking at their equation $r=3(1-\cos \theta)$ it is clear they meant $r=3/2,\theta=\pi/3.$ I would agree text or source should have written $B(3/2,\pi/3).$

Comment: @coffeemath man Idk why but I still couldn't solve it even after making r = 3/2. If you could help me out with that as well I'd really appreciate it. I keep finding (21/4) / 0.

Comment: I take it the 5 answers you mention were "multiple choice", where you were supposed to pick 1 of them. Is that right? The method I'd use would be to convert the equation to rectangular and then use implicit differentiation to get $y'$ in terms of $x,y.$ Then it only remains to get the Cartesian coordinates for $B$ and plug them into the above $y'$ formula.

Comment: Still waiting for you to answr the question of my comment...

Comment: Well I went through it and got that the slope dy/dx is undefined at the given point. Makes me think the problem statement is in error, maybe some typo. If you have a copy of the test could you put a photo of just the question here in your questionn??

Comment: @coffeemath really sorry about the late response. It was night where live. About your question, yes it was multiple choice. I added the question's screenshot. It's in Turkish but it says what I say ( slope of tangent line of bla bla bla ). I used (rcost + r'sint) / (-rsint + r'cost) formula. I also used an online calculator that calculates slope, it said the result is tan(90) which is idk, its i guess either infinite or undefined. I wanna add this, about the formula I've just said, we only plug in r (or f(theta) ) so the length r is uncessary for the slope? You just plug in the angle? Right?

Comment: @coffeemath to be precise, (I realized this part later) it actually says find the slope angle (eğim açısı) of the tangent line of polar curve at point B. Idk idk if it's different than just the slope. (I guess they're the same now that I searched a little).

Comment: OK and you are right. I found the same formula as you cite for dy/dx in polar coords. I also got denominator zero (so tangent line is vertical). This is the same as saying slope is tan(90) since tan(90) is undefined. Note that the formula used has each of  r, r', and theta (which the formula uses "t" for). So no, we do not "just plug in the angle".

Comment: @coffeemath what I meant by just plugging in the angle was this, r actually defines the curve so it's f(t) and let's say it is r = f(t) = 1 + cost. When we use the formula I mentioned, we plug in f(t) (or r since they refer to the same thing) and it's derivative to the formula we get something that doesn't include r. So when we were to find the slope at point, say A(r, theta), we will only have to use theta of point A to find the slope at point A, and from that I assume that no matter what that r value is (since it just describes the length), the slope will be the same for same theta.

Comment: If you say $r=f(t)$ and proceed to plug in $r,r'$ along with $t$ it does not matter at all whether you instead plug in $f(t),f'(t)$ rather than $r,r'.$ They are the same things, and each varies as $t$ varies.

Comment: Another note about your last comment: A varying point on a polar graph is not just a function of the angle. A polar graph is a graph where the radius is a function of the angle. Even if you know what the radius will end up being, it is still the case that the formula for dy/dx relies not only on the fixed radius and angle, it also depends on the derivative of the radius with respect to the angle. Just knowing what the radius and angle end up being, you cannot get the derivative of the radius with respect to the angle without using the *formula* for radius in terms of variable angle.

Comment: @coffeemath oh I guess I just got something wrong about the formula. In it, there is r and r', I thought we plug in r=f(t) for r and r'=f'(t) for r' in the formula but I guess we plug in the distance to the point A for r, and r'=f'(t) for r' in the formula. So we use both distance and the angle of the point A(dist, angle) to find the slope of the tangent line at A. So to make sure I got it correct, I tried to resolve the question in post and I got 3/0 as result ( instead of (21/4) / 0 which I found in the first place without having a proper knowledge about the problem ) was it what you found?

Comment: I also got $3/0$ using that formula.

Comment: Okay then now it made sense thank you for your effort again